# shrarepoint webpart adding a method in ascx

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-enterprise

I need to add a method in ascx which has some parameters and one of parameter is `ResolveUrl(Eval("PageAbsoluteURL").ToString())`

when i am trying its throwing me error

i am attaching the code here can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong here

```
<td>
 <%= sample("ResolveUrl(Eval("PageAbsoluteURL").ToString()", rdoLiteratureList.SelectedValue, sap.stm, "", true)%>

     </td>
      <td >  
     <a id="lnkDoc" href='<%# ResolveUrl(Eval("PageAbsoluteURL").ToString()) %>' runat="server"      target="_blank" > Click here </a>
```

in the above code the first parameter i need to pass  href value

Comment: whats the error?

Comment: is your method visible from design-time, e.g. protected?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this and see if the error is gone:

```
<a id="lnkDoc" href="<%#=ResolveUrl(Eval("PageAbsoluteURL").ToString()) %>" runat="server"      target="_blank" > Click here </a>
```